# Reg Multiple msi projects

Tags: windows-installer

Is there any way to execute msi as per user choice?.
Like if we install office it asks what are the features we want to install (Excel ,Word and etc). i want an installer which should ask for user's choice and according to choice it should run some .msi files..

let me know if u find it difficult to understand...

Answer (score 0):

Write your own executable with a dialog that allows the user to select their options and then launches the respective MSIs using ShellExecute.